# .DismissModalViewController closes all my pages. Why?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am using an image picker in my xamarin forms in order to pick an image from gallery to my program...
But, only in IOS device, when I close the image picker using

```
imagePicker.DismissModalViewController(true);
```

all my pop ups that is opened are closed with the imagePicker...
Does someone know why? or how I can solve that?
I am using DependencyService to do that in both

This is the code in IOS project

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using neoFly_Montana.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using neoFly_Montana.Interface;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(PicturePickerImplementation))]
namespace neoFly_Montana.iOS
{
public class PicturePickerImplementation : IPicturePicker
{
    TaskCompletionSource<Stream> taskCompletionSource;
    UIImagePickerController imagePicker;

    public Task<Stream> GetImageStreamAsync()
    {
        // Create and define UIImagePickerController
        imagePicker = new UIImagePickerController
        {
            SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary,
            MediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.AvailableMediaTypes(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary)
        };

        // Set event handlers
        imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia += OnImagePickerFinishedPickingMedia;
        imagePicker.Canceled += OnImagePickerCancelled;

        // Present UIImagePickerController;
        UIWindow window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
        var viewController = window.RootViewController;
        viewController.PresentModalViewController(imagePicker, true);

        // Return Task object
        taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Stream>();
        return taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }

    void OnImagePickerFinishedPickingMedia(object sender, UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs args)
    {
        UIImage image = args.EditedImage ?? args.OriginalImage;

        if (image != null)
        {
            // Convert UIImage to .NET Stream object
            NSData data = image.AsJPEG(1);
            Stream stream = data.AsStream();

            // Set the Stream as the completion of the Task
            taskCompletionSource.SetResult(stream);
        }
        else
        {
            taskCompletionSource.SetResult(null);
        }
        imagePicker.DismissModalViewController(true);
    }

    void OnImagePickerCancelled(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        taskCompletionSource.SetResult(null);
        imagePicker.DismissModalViewController(true);
    }
}
}
```

I am using RG.PLUGIN.POPUP

Comment: Try:  UIWindow window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
        var viewController = window.RootViewController;  viewController.DismissModalViewController(true);

Comment: `all my pop ups`, what are those? Xamarin.Form pages, system dialogs, ....?

Comment: Rg.Plugins.Popup